# Hibernate softdelete - column index out of range exception while soft delete

Tags: java, hibernate, exception

I'm getting the below exception while soft delete. I'm not sure where the mistake is? Can any one help me on this. Thanks in advance

```
    org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not delete: [com.ItemResponse#47379632]; SQL [UPDATE fs_item_response SET deleted = '1' WHERE itemresponseid = ?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not delete: [com.ItemResponse#47379632]        
    Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 2, number of columns: 1.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.SimpleParameterList.bind(SimpleParameterList.java:53)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.SimpleParameterList.setLiteralParameter(SimpleParameterList.java:114)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.bindLiteral(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2176)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.setInt(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:1214)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.setInt(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:677)
    at org.hibernate.type.IntegerType.set(IntegerType.java:64)
    at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeSet(NullableType.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeSet(NullableType.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2521)
    ... 80 more
    <hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.DataResponse" dynamic-insert="true"
        dynamic-update="true" table="response" where="deleted != 1">
    <id name="id" column="dataresponseid" type="long"
            unsaved-value="-1">
            <generator class="seqhilo">
                <param name="max_lo">1</param>
                <param name="sequence">dataresponse_seq</param>
            </generator>
        </id>           
        <version name="version" column="version"
            type="java.lang.Integer" unsaved-value="null" />            
        <property name="deleted" type="long"  >
            <column name="deleted" default="0"/>
        </property>
        <property name="textResponse" type="java.lang.String"
            update="true" insert="true" column="textresponse" />
        <many-to-one name="dataDetail" class="com.DataDetail" cascade="none" update="true" insert="true" foreign-key="fk_datadetail_datadetailid" column="datadetailid" not-null="true" />
                <sql-delete>UPDATE response SET deleted = '1' WHERE dataresponseid = ?</sql-delete>
    </class>
    </hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Internally, when the delete request is issued on versioned entities, it seems that Hibernate is also passing the version number as a second parameter. So you need to modify your SQLDelete statement to accept the version parameter as well.

Ex.

```
UPDATE response SET deleted = '1' WHERE itemresponseid = ? AND version = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

The data type of `deleted` is `long`. So remove the `''` from `SET deleted = '1'`

Comment: Even after removing the `''` from `SET deleted = '1'`, I'm getting the same error. The below error is suspicious : `Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 2, number of columns: 1`.   Although the update query is displaying correctly in error log but not sure why its displaying the indext out of range exception. `org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not delete: [com.ItemResponse#47379632]; SQL [UPDATE fs_item_response SET deleted = 1 WHERE itemresponseid = ?];`

Answer (score 0):

The above issue is resolved with the below :

UPDATE response  SET deleted = 1 WHERE itemresponseid = ? and -1 != ?

@Yohan Liyanage, Thanks for the clue.